# Re-Show Tab Bar when navigation controller popped

Tags: ios, tabs

I have a Tab Bar Controller, with 1 tab being a UINavigationController. The root of the UINavigationController is a UITableViewController. When I select an item on the TableView, I push to a new UIViewController, which sets

```
HidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
```

and the tab bar disappears as expected.

Now, when I press the back button on the nav bar to pop the view controller back to the Tab Bar Controller containing the UINavigationController that has UITableViewController root, the tab bar won't reappear.

Furthermore, Tab Bar Controller's and UINavigationController's ViewWillAppear are not called when I press the back button. I have this following code, but since it's not called, probably not useful. Excuse the Xamarin, don't think it has bearing on the question.

```
public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
{
    base.ViewWillAppear(animated);
    TabBar.Hidden = false;
    UIView.Animate(0.5, () => {
        TabBar.Frame = new CGRect(
            0,
            View.Frame.Bottom - 49.0f,
            View.Frame.Size.Width,
            49.0f);
    }, () => {
        TabBar.Hidden = false;
    });
}
```

Comment: If you change it to ViewDidAppear does it work?

Comment: How are you presenting and dismissing your controllers, can you post?

Comment: only navigation.PushViewController(x ,y)

Comment: So you're calling push then pop and you're saying the above code is not firing even with a println in it?

Comment: Can you add a viewDidDisappear to this class and tell me if it fires (with a println) when you push the second view?

Comment: i think this is similar to my problem but the tab bar controller really screws everything up. the entire Navigation Root ViewController's View disappears when I do this: http://davidebenini.it/2009/01/03/viewwillappear-not-being-called-inside-a-uinavigationcontroller/